# CSS child divs outside the parent

Tags: css

This is the parent div:

```
.navi {
    width: 400px;
    height: 30px;
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

And these are the child divs inside:

```
.aktuelleseite {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #404040;
}

.blatt {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

They are falling out of the parent div, how can i make them always stay inside of it?

This is the part of the function.php

```
  if(!in_array(1,$blaetter) AND count($blaetter) > 1)
      {
      if(!in_array(2,$blaetter)) { echo '<a href="http://www.stylechica.de/hosen/' . $navi . '" class="blatt">1</a>...'; }
      else { echo '<a href="http://www.stylechica.de/hosen/' . $navi . '">1</a>'; }
      }

   foreach($blaetter AS $blatt)
      {
      if($blatt == $seite) { echo '<div class="aktuelleseite">' . $blatt . '</div>'; }
      else { echo '<a href="http://www.stylechica.de/hosen/' . $navi . 'seite-' . $blatt . '/" class="blatt">' . $blatt . '</a>'; }
      }

   if(!in_array($maxseite,$blaetter) AND count($blaetter) > 1)
      {
      if(!in_array(($maxseite-1),$blaetter)) { echo '...<a href="http://www.stylechica.de/hosen/' . $navi . 'seite-' . $maxseite . '/" class="blatt">' . $maxseite . '</a>'; }
      else { echo '<a href="http://www.stylechica.de/hosen/' . $navi . 'seite-' . $maxseite . '/" class="blatt">' . $maxseite . '</a>'; }
      }

   }
?>    </div>
```

I call it with:

```
<?php
$wieviele_seiten = $json_output["ProductsSummary"]["TotalPages"];
$navi = blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);
echo $navi;
?>
```

You can see he result here: www.stylechica.de/hosen if it not loeads jus reload it, sometimes the API makes trouble

Comment: can you recreate it in a fiddle ? Try adding `float:left;` to the children

Comment: Illustrate your scenario

Comment: I edithe question so you can see more

Comment: ok Iremove the overflow but how to wrap the element and clear?

Comment: Can you post the HTML you have?

Comment: Your <div class="navi"></div> is showing blank. The php you used to inject is not taking elements within it. Try removing white spaces if any to resolve the issue. Nothing wrong about your code. @CaroFiedler

Comment: I don't see/have any white spaces, so sick of CSS :(

Comment: Does anybody else have any idea? I allready tryed all the suggestions right now

Comment: Try this `<?php$wieviele_seiten = $json_output["ProductsSummary"]["TotalPages"];$navi = blaetterfunktion($seite,  $wieviele_seiten);echo $navi;?>` - @CaroFiedler The one without any white-spaces

Comment: I removed the second white space between $seite, and $wieviele_seiten but stil not working

Answer (score 0):

You have set `width` to the children elements. Try:

```
.aktuelleseite {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #404040;
}

.blatt {
    display: inline-block;    
    height: 20px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #C0C0C0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #404040;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[Try it in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8hG7/)

Comment: Now I solved it, the parent div should be over <?php $wieviele_seiten = $json_output["ProductsSummary"]["TotalPages"];
$navi = blaetterfunktion($seite, $wieviele_seiten);echo $navi;?> instead in the function.php